# How is it possible to automate cropping using selenium?

Tags: css, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to simulate a cropping feature, I know its not possible to simulate human cropping, but the image I will be cropping is 1 size and I want to crop it by setting the cropping WebElement in a fixed size every time I run the test.

to do this I need to know how can I change the cropping style, to set its size...so I can click on the cropping button to get cropping ability (this is simple) and now to set its style so I can get its rectangle.

this is the style prop im talking about:

[image]

so I can do something like this:

```
val cropButton = driver.findElement(By.xpath( """//*[@id="new_company"]/input[4]"""))
    saveButton.click()

driver.executeScript("something to set the style")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the style attribute with your on string.

```
String newStyle = "width: 238px ..."
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='new_company']/input[4]"));
js.executeScript("arguments[0].setAttribute('style', '" + newStyle + "')", element);
```